# JACK turns off other sound

Tags: sound, jack

I have a midi keyboard connected to qSynth through jack, which works fine. But when I try to play other sound(from chrome, vlc, etc.) it is completely silent. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JACK breaks audio. How do I fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/729990/jack-breaks-audio-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JACK takes exclusive control over your sound card. If you want to use an application that does not support JACK natively, you can use PulseAudio as an intermediate layer. See [this guide](http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/PulseOnJack) or the [Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ProAudioIntro/1204#The_Pulse_Audio_to_Jack_Bridge_-_using_both_at_once) for details.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, but I am having trouble finding my asound.conf or asoundrc. Create one?

Comment: Yes, create `/etc/asound.conf` for system-wide settings, or `~/.asoundrc` for the current user.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ProAudioIntro/1204#The_Pulse_Audio_to_Jack_Bridge_-_using_both_at_once) at the Community Wiki.

Comment: I got this to work but the sound is quite  a bit quieter now. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the volume controls for PulseAudio?

Comment: yeah they're all at 100%

Comment: Well, my last idea is `alsamixer`.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.