# Volume too low after connecting Pulseaudio to JACK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I followed the tutorial mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486513/jack-turns-off-other-sound) but after the sound is much quieter even at 100%. I have loooked at the Pulseaudio volume controls and alsamixer and they are all also at 100.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem: I've used `pactl load-module module-jack-sink; pactl load-module module-jack-source` on startup while using QJackCtl to redirect PulseAudio output to Jack, it worked but the sound was quiet.

I've found out that if my volume level was, say, 30% before I've started QJackCtl, it seems to think that this is the max volume it can get, so this volume will be 100%.

So I just turn volume to maximum and started QJackCtl and now sound volume is okay.

Hope this helps.